# Devexpress Gridview Hide Editform in asp.net mvc

Tags: model-view-controller, gridview, devexpress, hide

If my CustomerName FieldName equals to "MyCustomer" , i want to hide editing for that row.

If **customername == "MyCustomer** , **hide** column **editing**.

How can i hide column editing according to "MyCustomer"?

```
settings.Columns.Add(s =>
{
s.FieldName = "CustomerName";
s.Caption = "Customer";
s.Name = "CustomerColumn";
s.ColumnType = MVCxGridViewColumnType.ComboBox;
var comboBoxProperties = s.PropertiesEdit as ComboBoxProperties;
comboBoxProperties.DataSource =Model.CustomerList;
comboBoxProperties.TextField = "Customer_Name";
comboBoxProperties.ValueField = "Customer_Id";
comboBoxProperties.ValueType = typeof(int);
comboBoxProperties.ClientInstanceName = "CustomerColumn";
});
```

Any help will be appreaciated with points.

Answer (score 1):

```
settings.CommandButtonInitialize = (s, e) => {
    if (e.ButtonType == ColumnCommandButtonType.Edit) {
        MVCxGridView g = s as MVCxGridView;
        var value = (int)g.GetRowValues(e.VisibleIndex, "RowFieldName"); //use a correct field name and cast a resultant value to a correct value type
        e.Visible = value > 10; // for example, only
    }
};
```

Fortunately , i have myself.I found a solution.
It works.Hope this helps who has the same problem in the future.